# Typescript compiler error when logging in with Facebook Authentication

Tags: facebook, typescript, firebase, angular, firebase-authentication

Typescript compiler error when logging in with Facebook Authentication.

The Facebook authentication works fine.
Its just the typescript compiler that doesn't like the response.

Typescript compiler error is: **"Property 'facebook' does not exist on type FirebaseAuthData".**

**Here is my code:**

```
 public loginWithFacebook():void{       
         this.ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData?)          {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {         

            //Error here - Doesnt like authData.facebook.
            let user = {
              email    : authData.facebook.email,
              password : null,
              uid: authData.uid
            }       

            this.addUser(user);
      }
    });
}
```

In the response of authData.facebook.email the error seems to be.
This code all works fine and runs.
But not the typescript compiler.

I need to go: authData.facebook in order to access the email field but typescript seems to get confused with what facebook is.

Comment: @David East do you have any idea how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using? And where are you getting your .d.ts file from?

Comment: Firebase API 2.0.2. I'm storing the firebase file locally

Comment: What about the .d.ts it's probably out of date or needs an update. Check the file it should show the version

Comment: Also, I've just tried it with version: Firebase v2.3.2 - ive downloaded the latest firebase.js - how to I get it to be file type ".d.ts?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that the main `firebase.d.ts` file is out of date. It's on version 2.0.2. It needs to be corrected (and I'll likely be sending in a PR).

But for now you can add this to the `firebase.d.ts` file to get moving.

```
interface FirebaseAuthData {
    uid: string;
    provider: string;
    token: string;
    expires: number;
    auth: Object;
    google?: FirebaseAuthDataProvider;
    facebook?: FirebaseAuthDataProvider;
}

interface FirebaseAuthDataProvider {
    accessToken: string;
    cachedUserProfile: any;
    displayName: string;
    email?: string;
    id: string;
    profileImageURL: string;
}
```

This will update the interfaces so the compilation works.

Comment: Thanks David. Il try that next

Comment: It should work, but I'll need to get DefinitelyTyped updated.

Comment: I tried adding those interfaces to top of firebase.d.ts file but now I get a lot more typescript compiler errors

Comment: Can you send me the latest firebase.js and firebase.d.ts files?

Comment: I updated it to what I have above and it worked for me. This copy the contents of this file into your `firebase.d.ts` file: https://gist.github.com/davideast/820bec4aa8e525460ced

Comment: However, once DefinitelyTyped is updated you should use tsd to manage your typings. http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/